# SQL Server: Select query runs fine in TOAD, but throws exception in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Can any one please help me. I am getting below error:

org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)

. . .
. . .
. . .

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Confirm' to data type int.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:368)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2820)

Comment: `Any idea why I am getting this` because you have a coding error.

Comment: please add that query in your question.

Comment: Toad does not need to convert the values from "varchar" on column "confirm". Hibernate needs some conversion helper from "varchar" to "int" as it is not a automatic conversion. "Varchar" can contain non numeric values.

Comment: @Konrad: You are correct. that helps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ScaryWombat: Thanks for your kind suggestion.